# Возможна ли в Unity в scrollbar прокрутка кнопкой?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Возможна ли в Unity в scrollbar прокрутка кнопкой?
Создать кнопку и по нажатию она  будет немного прокручивать scrollbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прокрутка кнопкой возможна, если использовать [ScrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-horizontalNormalizedPosition.html) или [ScrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-verticalNormalizedPosition.html) (в зависимости от того какой скролл горизонтальный или вертикальный). Внутри ScrollRect можно позиционировать содержимое через NormalizedPosition, который измеряется от 0.0f до 1.0f.

Вопрос тут будет заключаться только в том, как вы будет прикидывать размер содержимого. Например если у вас скролл в котором 10 одинаковых по размеру элементов, то каждый из них это 0.1f. Также если вас интересует просто небольшая прокрутка с помощью кнопок, то можете просто подобрать небольшой коэффициен на который будете перемещать содержимое.